# How to create folder by overwriting an existing folder

Tags: vb.net

The following code copies `C:\Book1.txt` and pastes to the Temp folder as `Book2.txt` by overwriting and existing file:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("C:\Book1.txt", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "Book2.txt", True)
```

I need the same action for a directory.

Comment: Either you can write code to create the destination directory and copy the files and repeat for subdirectories or perhaps the [FileSystem.CopyDirectory Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127957.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are after [FileSystem.CopyDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127958(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Test", "C:\Test2", True)
```

This will overwrite the directory *Test2* with *Test*.

It will overwrite all the existing files in *Test2* however it won't remove files.

For example let's say the directory *Test* has the following files:

- Book1.txt
- Book2.txt

And directory *Test2* has the following files:

- Book1.txt
- Book3.txt

What `FileSystem.CopyDirectory` will do is overwrite `Book1.txt`, copy in `Book2.txt` and leave `Book3.txt` in tact.